# Is it possible to plot bars with filled pattern in Matlab

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure, figure

[image]

Is it possible to plot bars with filled pattern in Matlab, like this figure?

I attempted to use `applyhatch_pluscolor` [link](https://ww2.mathworks.cn/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24021-hatch-fill-patterns-plus-color-invert) however, I couldn't make it work (attempt below). Is there an easy / feasible alternative?

---

Test code:

```
bar(rand(3,4));
[im_hatch,colorlist] = applyhatch_pluscolor(gcf,'\-x.',1,[],[],150);
```

[image]

Then I changed the source code, from `bits = hardcopy(h,'-dzbuffer',['-r' num2str(dpi)]);` to `bits = print(h,'-RGBImage',['-r' num2str(dpi)]);`.

I got the figure below. However, this is still far away form the desired result.

[image]

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html

Comment: @RobertHarvey that comment doesn't really help in answering the question. Short answer: there is no in-built functionality in MATLAB for plotting bars with hatched patterns. However, people have found various workarounds, see for example https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/ or https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24021-hatch-fill-patterns-plus-color-invert.

Comment: I got some errors when using it. I'm using matlab2017.

Comment: Such a detailed description of your problem....